# How can I hide a ul inside li?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Please tell me how can I hide `ul` child element inside each `li`, by clicking `li` link.
I mean if someone clicks `Alink`, `A1` and `A2` hides.

This is my HTML code :

```
[Code missing]
```

And here is the jQuery code, but it doesn't work :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ListGrayCircle li").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').hide();     
  });
});
```

Comment: Please also post  your html code.

Comment: Your HTML code is not visible.  Perhaps you failed to indent it so that it would be treated as code?

Comment: @Conspicuous Compiler: Nope he has no code inside his questino.

Comment: Your jQuery code looks good, so it's likely a problem with your HTML. I assume the click event never fires or the nested <ul> element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Without the html I'll assume that the inner [ul] to be hidden is not within the [a] tag. Your code should run fine if the user clicks the [li] but if it's an [a] link within it it won't. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ListGrayCircle li").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul').hide();
    });
});
```